# How to use sqlite in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I am using vc# for GUI and vc++ for processing part as it includes 3D modeling.I am using SQLite and it works fine with vc# but i am not sure how to import SQLite libraries in vc++.visual studio 2008 supports SQLite i guess.how to use the same in visual studio 2012  for c++?
does visual studio 2012 requires additional drivers or something?can somebody give me step by step installation procedure of SQLite in Visual studio 2012 for c++?

Answer (score 0):

There is now an official installer out on this page here:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

It will install the design-time components into VS2012, as well as the official System.Data.Sqlite binaries.

There are many downloads on that page, the one you need is about half way down and you can get there by searching for this:

sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe

here is a direct link: http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe

PS: It is important to note that the design time components are not supported for VS Express due to licensing restrictions.

Comment: I am using VS express for windows desktop edition.is there any way to make use of SQLite?

Comment: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q4         possible check this website